# Big "half" mouse pointer won't change

Tags: mouse, cursor

I'll start by saying that I'm brand new to Linux and to fiddling with the inner workings of an OS.  It's been a fun learning experience.

I started with 16.04 and upgraded to 17.04, then a fresh install of 17.10.  So far so good-- except for this weird mouse pointer that showed up on the upgrade to 17.04.  I thought it would go away with the fresh install of 17.10, but no.  Here is a pic of the cursor next to some current settings for it.   [Mouse 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRxF2.jpg)

See that tall pointy thing that looks like the right half of a Christmas Tree?  That's my mouse pointer.  It also looks like the right half of a highly magnified arrowhead.  The cursor is totally functional, works fine on the desktop and in applications.  You just have to use the very tippy top of the tree as your target pointing zone.  But it's not really what I'm after.  :)

What is maddening is that it won't change to a regular pointer.  Changing to Redglass or DMZ-Black, for example does change it slightly but it still has the same shape.  I tried altering the cursor size (now at 18), changing the theme, toggling the Accessibility options, even tried different mouse hardware, but no luck.

Here's where it gets weirder......I fiddled with the Display settings.  It's currently in Landscape mode.  But any other mode-- Portrait, Portrait Reversed or Landscape Reversed changed the cursor to what it SHOULD look like. Of course, those modes aren't really usable.

Furthermore, I took a Screenshot of the screen for this post to show you the mouse cursor-- and the screenshot shows a CORRECT cursor!  Argh!!!  So the enclosed pic is actually a photo of my display screen.

Anybody have a clue what is going on here?  Video card?  Memory?  Settings?

Thanks in advance for any insight or suggestions,

KW

Comment: Showing as it should in the screenshot makes you think indeed. Please [edit] and post the hardware specifications regarding graphics so we can start with something. Settings is also plausible, some glitch in the theme you're using, etc. But you should know what you changed or been fiddling with before that happened.