# ubuntu 17.10 cursor split

Tags: 17.10

Since I upgraded my ubuntu to the last version, its mouse cursor has been split. I don't know how to fix it.

This issue is on GNOME (Wayland desktop environment) only.

My mouse cursor:

[image: Taken by mob camera 1]

[image: Taken by mob camera 2]

It's a labtop acer Aspire 3620.

CPU:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 13
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor         1.60GHz
stepping    : 8
microcode   : 0x20
cpu MHz     : 1596.025
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 2
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx bts cpuid
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3192.05
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

RAM:

```
MemTotal:        2051776 kB
MemFree:          161360 kB
MemAvailable:     735688 kB
Buffers:           81076 kB
Cached:           913884 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1063652 kB
Inactive:         726024 kB
Active(anon):     784268 kB
Inactive(anon):   243592 kB
Active(file):     279384 kB
Inactive(file):   482432 kB
Unevictable:         672 kB
Mlocked:             672 kB
HighTotal:       1174408 kB
HighFree:          15008 kB
LowTotal:         877368 kB
LowFree:          146352 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2097148 kB
Dirty:              2692 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        795412 kB
Mapped:           429584 kB
Shmem:            252296 kB
Slab:              50920 kB
SReclaimable:      29632 kB
SUnreclaim:        21288 kB
KernelStack:        6088 kB
PageTables:        19520 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3123036 kB
Committed_AS:    8501252 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       24568 kB
DirectMap2M:      888832 kB
```

VGA: onboard

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/974739/20275

Comment: @int_ua Totaly yeah but different in types of problem.

Comment: May be related to https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33183 Nothing else that's similar enough comes up in Google. Add your hardware and drivers, please.

Comment: @int_ua I added them.